# Jquery sortable plugin doesn't allow initiation of hover functions while dragging an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this problem:
When a menu element (using the [sortable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)) is being dragged and hovers another element, a function is supposed to start. I see that while the sortable plugin is initialized it ignores the hover functions written elsewhere in the code.

How can i make it fire the hover function while I'm dragging an element and I hover over the intended element?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This not very clear to be honest... Could you make a test case on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to illustrate the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

### You will need to use the sortable over event:

```
Supply a callback function to handle the over event as an init option.
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   over: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
Bind to the over event by type: sortover.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "sortover", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});

$("#sortable").sortable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
         alert( 'The Sortable Over Event Just Fired!!' );
        }
        });
```

Comment: Hi. Could you maybe make me an example in Jsfiddle? As i don't undersand why the sortable plugin has to be initiated twice :)